# What are merge fields in Apex and why are the called so?

Tags: visualforce, merge-field

What are merge fields in Apex and why are the called so?

As far as I can infer from how the `merge field` notion is used in [the](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/units/secdev_inject_preventing_xss_inforce) Trailhead, for example:

> If you inspect the Visualforce code, you see all the **merge fields** rendered with escape=”false”.

the `merge field` is just Visualforce attribute (just like `aura:attribute` in Lightning).

Is it correct? And why are they called so?

There is no more need to answer what a merge field is. I found an [article](http://writeforce.blogspot.com/2014/08/using-merge-fields-in-visualforce-pages.html) on it.

> **Merge fields** are an important part of building visualforce pages. They allow you to embed property or object values in your apex controller directly into the HTML generated by the corresponding Visualforce page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "merge field" simply means an area (the "field") where output from a function or expression is "merged" into the final output. In other words, the source code is basically a template, and some parts can be dynamically updated via the merge field syntax. One of the earliest versions of merge fields I recall was the "mail merge," where you'd place fields inside a Microsoft Word document, feed it a list of names, and you could print out a personalized set of letters for each person in the list.

Merge fields are not specifically attributes, variables, etc. They're just areas where the Visualforce expression engine is invoked. For example, you can write the following in a Visualforce page:

```
{!NOW()}
```

And it would output the current date and time. You can also write things like:

```
{!1+2}
```

And the page, you would see the result, 3.

The most typical use case is to "bind" an element to an attribute. For example, we often write code like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
```

Which tells Visualforce that the Account.Name field should be rendered as an input text, and honor field level security.

Note that merge fields are used throughout Salesforce: Custom Buttons and Links,  Visualforce, Apex Code, Lightning Components, Flows, and many other features. Most of them look like `{!...}`, but there are some special exceptions, so whenever you're not sure, make sure you check the documentation.